# Results in ascending order with cursor

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I have the following My Guitar Shop exercise in my SQL II course and am stumped with the part about getting the results in ascending order through the cursor. Any advice is appreciated.

Here are my instructions:

"Write a script that  utilizes a cursor to print the lastname of each customer in the customers table along with the number of orders that customer has placed.

Print the results to the screen in ascending order by number of order placed.

Include a total at the end that shows the total number of orders placed."

Here's my code:

```
USE MyGuitarShop;

/* Write a script that  utilizes a cursor to print the lastname of each customer in the customers table 
along with the number of orders that customer has placed.  
Print the results to the screen in ascending order by number of order placed. 
Include a total at the end that shows the total number of orders placed.*/

    DECLARE @CustID int;
    DECLARE @CustLastName varchar(60);
    DECLARE @TotalOrders int;

    SET @TotalOrders = 0;
    
    DECLARE Orders_Cursor CURSOR
    FOR
        SELECT CustomerID, LastName
        FROM Customers
    
    OPEN Orders_Cursor;
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM Orders_Cursor INTO @CustID, @CustLastName

    DECLARE @OrderCount int;
        
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    BEGIN
        PRINT @CustLastName + ': ' + CONVERT(varchar,@OrderCount);

        SELECT @OrderCount = COUNT(OrderID) 
        FROM Orders
        WHERE CustomerID = @CustID
        ORDER BY COUNT(OrderID) ASC;

        SET @TotalOrders = @TotalOrders + @OrderCount
            
        FETCH NEXT FROM Orders_Cursor INTO @CustID, @CustLastName;
    END;
        
    PRINT 'Total number of orders placed: ' + CONVERT(varchar, @TotalOrders);
        
    CLOSE Orders_Cursor;
    DEALLOCATE Orders_Cursor;
```

Everything works accept the ascending order and I have spent hours and hours and cannot figure this out. Any tips to lead me in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: So add an Order By in your SQL in the cursor declaration

Comment: Learn to use SET to assign values to variables. Your COUNT statement will generate a single row - the ORDER BY clause has no logical effect. If you want to keep the cursor for some reason, then add an ORDER BY clause to the query that defines the cursor. Rarely is there a good reason to use a cursor in most production situations. As already demonstrated, a single query can produce the desired information. Generally we don't use PRINT in production code either. Not a particularly good exercise but I suppose one must learn cursors eventually

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,  you just need list all the customers with the order count.

You can create one cursor directly based on below SQL statement:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.LastName, COUNT(o.orderid) as orderCount FROM 
customers c LEFT JOIN  orders o
ON c.LastName = o.LastName GROUP BY c.LastName ORDER BY orderCount;
```

In your implementation,  in the sub-sql,  you query the order count for a specified customer and order by , the order by is useless for only one customer.

Comment: Thanks so much.  That makes total sense.  I felt like it was trying to Order By a single iteration of the loop too, but could not get it to work outside of the loop.  The table join below the Cursor declaration did the trick.  Thanks again!!